# Question Regarding Complete Normal Fans and Duality

Tags: convex-analysis, definition, duality-theorems, polytopes, discrete-geometry

I have a question regarding the definition of a normal fan. The definition is thus:

> "Given a non-empty polytope $P \subset \mathbb{R ^d}$, the normal fan
> $N(P)$ of $P$ is the fan consisting of, for each nonempty face of $P$,
> the linear functionals in $(\mathbb{R^d})^*$ that are maximized on
> that face. In other words, for each non-empty face $F$ of $P$, let
>
> $$N_F = \{\textbf{c} \in (\mathbb{R^d})^* \mid \textbf{c} \textbf{x}
> \geq \textbf{c} \textbf{y} \text{ for all }  \textbf{x}\in F,
>  \textbf{y} \in P\}.$$
>
> Then each $N_F$ is a cone generated by the normal vectors to the
> facets containing $F$, and these cones together form a complete fan
> $N(P)$".

It is to my understanding that a normal fan is complete, i.e. the union of all of the normal cones over their respective boundaries from said fan generates or gives back the ambient space, which in this case is $(\mathbb{R^d})^*$. However, isn't $(\mathbb{R^d})^* = \mathbb{R^d}$? I know that we can identify a vector space with its dual via the inner product, which in this case is just the standard dot product in $\mathbb{R^d}$. In other words, my question is whether $(\mathbb{R^d})^*$ is some other dual (adjoint) space (not just the whole $\mathbb{R^d}$)?

Any explanation or clarification is most welcomed.

The definitions come from this website (scroll to the bottom section 6.4):

https://riliu.math.ncsu.edu/724/notesse6.html

Edit: The reason for the question is that I am trying to prove a statement of the following form:

> If we have a closed convex polyhedron $C$ in $\mathbb{R^n}$, then the union of all
> normal cones $N_C(x)$, through $x$ taking the values from the boundary of
> $N_C(x)$, equals $\mathbb{R^n}$.

I think that showing that a normal fan is complete will answer this question directly, but I think there are issues with the ambient space being $(\mathbb{R^n})^*$ in the above definition. Or is there really an issue?

Comment: I think my problem with this questions is the following: why do you think that the setting of your question (normal fans of polytopes) has relevance for whether you can consider $(\Bbb R^d)^*$ as $\Bbb R^d$ or not?

Comment: @M.Winter please see the edit above. I am trying to prove a result which I've stated above. As it stands, it includes $\mathbb{R^n}$ not $(\mathbb{R^n})^*$. So my question is, does it technically matter whether we have the dual space or not? The definition I am trying to adapt uses the dual, which makes me think there is an issue.

Comment: This thing you want to prove is true but you need to use a different definition of the normal cone that actually lives in $\Bbb R^n$? Why not do that? Every vector $x\in\Bbb R^n$ is part of some such normal cone because the linear functional $\langle x,\cdot\rangle$ is maximized on some face of $P$, and so $x$ is in the normal cone of that face.

Comment: For aesthetic reasons, I'd first do the whole proof as you suggested, showing that the normal fan covers all of $(\mathbb R^d)^*$ and then, only at the very end, say that, given an inner product, we can identify $(\mathbb R^d)^*$ with $\mathbb R^d$, move the normal fan to $\mathbb R^d$, and say that it covers this space. My aesthetic reason is that the essential idea of the proof (and of normal fans in general) works in any real vector space, even without an inner product. An inner product is used only in the extraneous step of moving everything to $\mathbb R^d$.